# Send carriage return

Tags: javascript, arraybuffer, mit-scratch, uint8array

I'm trying to connect through serial [Scratchx](https://github.com/LLK/scratchx/wiki) and a piece of hardware similar to Arduino.

Scratchx lets you send data in JS this way:

```
var pingCmd = new Uint8Array(1);
pingCmd[0] = 1;
device.send(pingCmd.buffer);
```

Problem is the hardware firmware expects a string terminated with a carriage return, not an array buffer.

Can you imagine a way to send this carriage return? I'm giving up, but... any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Inserting \n at the of string then convert it to Uint8Array ?

Comment: I did it before posting but with no luck. I found hald a solution meantime but it's unrelated to the question

Comment: Well, if the requirement really is a _carriage return_, then I'd suggest to try `\r` or `\r\n` rather than `\n`.